# MAMP Pro security warning

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I've used MAMP then I bought upgrade for MAMP PRO and then few days later I started to feel that the option to run apache/mysql as www/mysql user just slowing my production time with it's annoying permission problems.
The best solution so far is to run apache/mysql as a local user but you have a scary message there saying :

'For security reasons, it's recommended to run the servers as 'www/mysql' when your Mac is connected to the Internet.'

My computer is connected to the internet all the time so to it is imposible for me to turn off the inet connection while working.

What I wan't to know are :
How big the risk to run apache as a local user? ( I'm using mac with firewall on and little snitch installed )

I've searched throught their forum and no detail asnwer from the developer. I have asked at their forum and also send them support email, and they didn't answer for months

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here. In [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress), is recommended that "All files should be owned by your user account, and should be writable by you." But then MAMP says different!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the support email reply I just received from appsolute:

> "When you mac is connected to the internet" means using your Mac as a live server, that would probably be better wording. As long as you are keeping your Mac up to date with the standard updates you don't need to worry about using username/username to run Apache and MySQL. It's a lot easier with permissions, I use them.

Comment: Hi, Lucky you. I had been waiting been waiting they response for years with no luck. They really have a bad reputation when handling support even for people who bought their software. I'm now no longer using MAMP. I use AMPPS now. Although the UI not as good as mamp but it works. I does have all of MAMP pro features and it's easier to use. It's free too